# How to specify a static folder in Koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

**index.js:** (placed inside of `server` folder.)

```
const serve = require('koa-static')
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(serve(__dirname + './public'));

app.listen(3000);

console.log('listening on port 3000');
```

I want to show `index.html`, which is located in `/public` folder.

When I start `index.js` above, I see `Not Found` on the browser.

`console.log` shows, it's referring to same folder where `index.js` is.

**UPDATE 1:**

`console.log(__dirname + './public');` shows

`/Users/askar/work/react/hub/server./public`,

but I need `/Users/askar/work/react/hub/public`

Comment: https://github.com/koajs/send

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

**Changed from** `app.use(serve(__dirname + './public'));`

**To** `app.use(serve('./public'));`

Reference: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/koajs/koajs_static_files.htm